# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'feather.compat'

Tags: python, module, feather

I installed feather using

```
conda install feather-format -c conda-forge
```

and I believe that it was successfully installed but when I try to run a program with

```
from feather.compat import pdapi
```

I get an error saying that there is no module named 'feather.compat'. How do I fix this?

Comment: does `import feather` work on its own?

Comment: I just changed it and ran it but now it gives an error that says cannot import name 'pdapi'

Comment: No I mean can you just write `import feather` on its own line, with nothing else after it - Does that work? If so: Then you at least have the package, and should `print(dir(feather))` to see all the possible modules you could import, if not: You did not install the package correctly (in the correct location, etc.)