# Feather.compat import ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'feather.compat'

Tags: python, pyarrow, feather

Same problem as defined in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845316/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-feather-compat), but there has been no solved answer. Wondering if there is something going on between **pyarrow** and **feather**.

I tried environments where:

- I installed with `conda install feather-format -c conda-forge`
- Installed with `pip install feather-format`

The error is occurring when calling:

```
from feather.compat import pdapi
```

I tried switching `feather` to `pyarrow` as a last resort with no luck.

Having trouble with line 14 from [the MicrobiomeHD source code](https://github.com/cduvallet/microbiomeHD/blob/master/src/data/clean_otu_and_metadata.py)

Failures with a Python 2.7 environment as described in the readme, as well as a Python 3 environment

Any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: If you named a file `feather.py`, don't do that.

Comment: There is no file named `feather.py`

Comment: From my understanding, `feather`'s use of `compat` and `pdapi` comes from `pyarrow` See: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/_modules/pyarrow/feather.html

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else using microbiomeHD in the future,
replace line 14:

`from pyarrow.compat import pdapi`

with:

`from pandas.core import common as pdapi`

in src/data/clean_otu_and_metadata.py

Comment: Cool, thanks for adding that. Have you found this to be able to run without fail and further modification?

Comment: Sure thing, It's a valuable resource so I figured I wouldn't be the only one still interested. I actually got hit with a division by zero error at the start of the analyses but the cleaned tables in feather format were produced so I didn't feel the need to continue.

Answer (score 0):

`feather.compat` [no longer exists](https://github.com/wesm/feather/tree/v0.4.0/python/feather) in feather 0.4.0. Most of the `feather` functionality has been moved to `pyarrow`, and `feather` itself is now a thin wrapper around `pyarrow.feather`. `feather.compat` was removed as part of that change. I don't think it was ever intended to be used from outside of `feather` itself.

New code you write should not rely on `feather.compat`, and old code will have to be adjusted.

Comment: Alright, that clarifies the problem a bit and explains why there aren't many docs for `feather`. Will try modifying the file I linked to and update it for this application.